# I'm trying to use Firebase to auth by using email/password and found this error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, dart-pub

```
I/FirebaseAuth(11262): Logging in as test@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  (11262): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  (11262): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(11262): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 9vxnYzLISWcna1UZUFhpg7SbdVI3 ).
```

and when I import my auth file, it don't use it,
My import in page:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'email_login_test_page_util/login_textfield.dart';
import 'widget_tree.dart';
> import 'auth.dart';
```

I try to fix it by try to track the error code but my code isn't run.

Comment: You have not mentioned the error, please share the actual error details for a better troubleshooting.

Comment: I try to make login by email/password but when I hit button Login(that should login) but it doesn't work. and terminal tells me error that I posted.

Comment: Hello again, actually, the 4 lines you have shared isn't the actual error. Those lines are just logs saying user is logging in without reCAPTCHA verification. If please share more logs from the terminal to see if there are any errors. Also, the code where the error happens is not also shared. Please share more details to help you out on this.

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried searching around with what you've shared. A possible reason might be your Firebase project might have Email Enumeration Protection turned on. You can try disabling it in Firebase Console and try again. To disable it, open this link: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings > Select your Firebase Project > Click on User Actions on the left panel > Dis-select Email Enumeration Protection.